# How to modify CSS in a specific page of the WP admin dashboard (backend)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm trying to remove both padding and the title of the dashboard page of the admin panel of WordPress. The dashboard was redesigned with the `"Welcome Dashboard for elementor" + Elementor`.

I tried this script:

```
var domainURL = window.location.origin;
var path = window.location.pathname;
if ((path == "/wp-admin/" || path == "/wp-admin" || path == "/wp-login.php") && domainURL+path)
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("h1").style.display = "none";
}
```

It is not working. Would you have fixes or ideas to achieve this, please?

Comment: The aim is to remove padding and h1 title off the page.

The CSS code working when applied to ALL admin pages is the following :

`#wpcontent {padding: 0px !important;}
.h1 {display: none !important;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject the css into the wordpress header to actually modify the wordpress css admin console. In your `function.php` file add the following:

```
<?php function theme_admin_css() {
echo '
<style>
/* ... Your custom css goes here ... */
</style>
'; }
add_action( 'admin_head', 'theme_admin_css' ); ?>
```

Now to easily find your the element you want to target and style you can do the following:

In your browser: Right click on the element > Inspect.
Find your element in the source code: Right Click > Copy > Copy selector

Now you can paste your selector in-between the style tag and customize it.

One more thing, you should use the `!important` statement (eg: `background-color:red!important`)

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) The main problem i have is that the #wpcontent element i need to modify is common to all the wp-admin pages, and i need to modify those elements only on one specific page, and not on the other ones. That means a js or php function to filter the page based on url or title for exemple.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the `<body>` classes contain a unique class specific to that one page (e.g. page name), you could add this as the first selector to your `CSS` code.

- If not, you can add a `CSS` classes to the `<body>` tag with [`admin_body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/)

```php
// Backend
function filter_admin_body_class( $classes ) {  
    // Current url
    $current_url = '//' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    // Get last part from url. Expl: index.php
    $last_part = basename( parse_url( $current_url, PHP_URL_PATH ) );
    
    if ( $last_part == 'index.php' ) {
        // String
        $classes .= 'my-custom-backend-class';
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'filter_admin_body_class', 10, 1 );
```

---

Additional: For frontend pages you could use [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/)

- Note: The [Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) of WooCommerce and WordPress can be used in your template files to change what content is displayed based on what conditions the page matches.

```php
// Frontend
function filter_body_class( $classes ) {
    // Returns true on the cart page.
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        // Array
        $classes[] = 'my-custom-frontend-class';
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'filter_body_class', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I stumbled across this, but eventually I was able to load a css file from my template in WP admin. So it shouldn't be necessary to inject a `<style>` element, and instead you can do:

```
function enqueue_admin_stylesheet()
{
    if ('a-specific-page' == get_current_screen()->base) {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'your-admin-css',
            sprintf('%s/assets/css/admin-style.css', get_template_directory_uri())
        );
    }
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin_stylesheet');
```